# Windows Phone 8 method LaunchUriAsync() is displayed as an unknown method

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I use the Windows Phone 8 system.uri launcher, LaunchUriAsync(), it is displayed as an error in IntelliSense.

This is not an error and works fine. The method arguments are correct and it works as expected.

How should I resolve this in IntelliSense without affecting possible future errors using the same class or method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an error is displayed in IntelliSense but not during the compilation, it's usually caused by third-party Visual Studio extensions, that use their own analysis engine.

First, try disabling your Visual Studio extensions to see whether it fixes the issue. Then, once you've located the culprit, try fiddling with it to understand why it detects your code as erroneous.

For instance, with Resharper, it's common that the cache gets corrupted. To fix that, open the Resharper options, and in the "General" tab, click on the "Clear Caches" button. Then restart Visual Studio. There's probably similar workarounds for other third-party syntax-analysis tools.